# Gerar publish Site Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic

Bom dia, necessito de publicar um site com estrutura do ionic(sei que a ideia principal dele é gerar app, porem temos esse app e ele tem que ser um site e um app ao mesmo tempo), qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Qual versão do ionic esta usando?

Comment: Estou usando a v1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, primeiramente gostaria de dizer que é algo que não recomendo ser feito, pois é contra a ideia do que o ionic permite.

Se você não estiver usando nenhum plug-in Cordova, então não há problema, basta mover o conteudo da pasta www para o seu servidor. O app será replicado lá, mas enfatizo algumas problemas nesta decisão:

- O navegador terá de ser bem atualizado, pois o ionic utiliza algumas funcionalidade mais recente
- O ionic não foi destinado a este uso
- A experiencia do usuário na versão web será claramente prejudicada.

**EDIT**
EXISTE ALGUM SUPORTE PARA WEB SITE: http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/ionic/ionic-1-2-is-out/

Comment: posso publicar no iis? se sim, qual a melhor forma?

Comment: Acredito que seja da mesma forma que publica, um site simples no iis, tem que testar.

Comment: @GabrielSouza funcinou? a Resposta que dei esta certa?

Comment: creio que sim, ainda estou fazendo testes, obrigado!

Comment: as rotas não estão funcionando :\

Comment: ta dando erro? tem print?

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado!!! Salvou a prátia!!!!